# Pandas: Group by Time, then plot density per group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to group a data frame by time and then plot the density of a variable for each subgroup. I'm doing:

```
myDf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('AS'))['myVar'].plot(kind='density')
```

Here's the result:

```
date
2006-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
2007-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
2008-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
2009-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
2010-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
Name: myVar, dtype: object
```

and the plot:

[image: output]

How do I add the correct legend to the plot? There's no way to know which line corresponds to which year right now.

Comment: in the plot call, add kwarg: `label=pd.TimeGrouper('AS'))['date']` (or something like, to get the date value) and then call `legend`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `legend` argument to `True`:

```
myDf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('AS'))['myVar'].plot(kind='density', legend=True)
```

Comment: `pd.TimeGrouper()` was deprecated in pandas. Now use `pd.Grouper()`.

Comment: Thanks, how could set them as subplots?